# Display only overlay map without Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a ImageMapType which overlays the Google Map (v3 API). This is the default view for my web application and the user can decide to hide the overlay pressing a button.

Can I avoid to load the Google Map tiles untill the overlay is shown?

I have seen in documentation that there's a parameter called *mapTypeId* which can be set to specific values, but it seems it's not possible something like: mapTypeId: NULL

Thanks,
   Riccardo

Comment: When you use a ImageMapType and this MapType is active the API will not load any other tiles than the tiles of the ImageMapType

Comment: In this example there are both ImageMapType and Google Maps, how can I disable Google Maps? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay

Answer (score 0):

I found this documentation page that was enlightening: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

First of all I forgave to assign to my ImageMapType options the max and min zoom levels, here's the resulting configuration:

```
var myMap = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl : function(coord, zoom) { /* ... */},
    tileSize : new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng : true,
    opacity : 1,
    name: 'torino1864',
    minZoom : MAP_MIN_ZOOM,
    maxZoom : MAP_MAX_ZOOM
});
```

Then I needed to instantiate the map object (as usual):

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas_placesList1864'), {
    center : MAP_INITIAL_CENTER,
    zoom : 11,
    minZoom : MAP_MIN_ZOOM,
    maxZoom : MAP_MAX_ZOOM,
    backgroundColor : '#000000',
    draggable : true,
    panControl : false,
    streetViewControl : false,
    zoomControl : true,
    mapTypeControl : false
});
```

And then (the part I was missing) the custom map must be registered as a mapType and that new mapType must be set:

```
map.mapTypes.set('torino1864', mapTiler);
map.setMapTypeId('torino1864');
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified it a bit:

```
var mapTiler = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl : function(coord, zoom) { return "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==";},
    tileSize : new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    name: 'blankTiles',
    minZoom : 0,
    maxZoom : 20
});

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
});

map.mapTypes.set('blankTiles', mapTiler);
map.setMapTypeId('blankTiles');
```